# Memory management of Audio Buffers between modules using c

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, queue, posix

i am working on architecture part of designing queue management & memory management, while creating data queue of some data type e.g int. now in multithreaded environment currently i will be having one consumer and one producer. in this case i am going to create two thread: one producer & one consumer in following way :

```
thread 1:
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (!condition)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
/* do something that requires holding the mutex and condition is true */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

thread2:

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
/* do something that might make condition true */
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

when producer produces data then it locks using mutex, put data in queue, signal using conditional variable & then release lock. consumer who waits for this signal it gets signal from producer thread, it locks queue internally, get data from queue & then release lock.

now here my question is if there are multiple consumer then how would i give them priority to give data them one by one. e.g if C1,C2 are consumers then how would i get priority to C1 first & then C2.

Comment: Since your producer activates the consumer it can simply send a signal to the respective consumer. No priorities are needed.

Comment: this seems perfect but can i have any identification about consumer? like thread id or consumer id? which is suitable solution for real time systems?

Comment: Unclear - do you want both C1 and C2 to get the same data, but C1 to get it first?  Please explain with more context.

Comment: @Martin James yes C1 to get first and then C2. in Real scenario, C2 needs to get data after C1 completes processing. any advise will be helpful.

Comment: Title suggests C, code is C. Why is there a C++ tag? POSIX would be a useful tag OTOH.

Comment: @MSalters updated Thanks. any idea about Audio Buffer efficient management in the context of Priority of Threads in above mentioned scenario?

Comment: @NishantBijaniA no problem, then,  Queue it to C1.  When C1 is done with it, C1 queues it to C2.  With audio, (and certainly with video), the buffers are not small, so you will probably be allocating and.or pooling buffers and so queueing pointers only.   I don't see how thread priority matters much, as you have described the system...